# div not positioning correctly in IE and Opera?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

i have a div which has a ribbon background image to it. I'm wanting to position my div with the ribbon backgrounnd over another div (div 2)  so it looks like the ribbon is wrapped around the 2nd div.

Now this works fine in Chrome and safari and i have had to use assitional css settings for firefox but IE and Opera both display my ribbon div about 25px higher than in chrome or safari.

Im not sure why this is and i cant seem to get it not to do positon right ( i need to move it down about 25px somehow only in these two browsers)

```
(div 1)
<div class="side-ribbon4"><img src="assets/img/sidebar/1.png" width="118" height="118" /></div>
```

div 1 css:

```
.side-ribbon4 {
    width:28px;
    height:21px;
    margin-left:111px;
    padding-right:0px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2273px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:30;


}
```

im placing it on top of this div (div 2)

div 2 css:

```
.categories-box2 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border:solid;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    /* [disabled]margin-left: 30px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position:relative;


}
```

Comment: Is `.side-ribbon4` inside `.categories-box2` in your markup?

Comment: no its not its on outside

Comment: Here's a fiddle. I took off the ridiculously large top margin, but the effect should be the same. I'm not sure what you're after. http://jsfiddle.net/ZnRSm/1/

Comment: Off topic, but Opera just said that they're moving to WebKit, so you'll have one less browser to worry about...

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnRSm/3/

```
.side-ribbon4 {position: relative;}
.categories-box2 {position: absolute;}

<div class="side-ribbon4">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/118x118" width="118" height="118" />
    <div class="categories-box2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

You'll want to do some study of CSS positioning and why it usually shouldn't be combined with floats. For one thing, absolutely-positioned elements are typically placed inside (and therefore relative to) relatively-positioned elements.

One other hint is that if you're having this type of problem, where browsers are rendering your layout differently, it probably means you have a bad layout. IE9+, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari are all quite standards-compliant and should show you nearly identical results.

Since you're new to SO I'll remind you to kindly select an answer, if one is provided, by clicking the checkmark.